# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'restaurant_id' cannot be null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying to store route id of a review (it contains restaurant id) in a variable called `restaurant_id` in a reviews table. This is the store function:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    if (! Auth::check()) {
        return redirect('/index');
    }

    $review = new Review;
    $review->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $review->restaurant_id = $request->route('id');
    $review->value = $request->input('value');
    $review->save();
}
```

This is the link on the restaurant profile that directs to the review template `Add review`. This is the action on the form:

```
{!!Form::open(['action' => ['ReviewsController@store'], 'method'=>'POST', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'])!!}
```

This is review template:

```
<html>
    {!!Form::open(['action' => ['ReviewsController@store',], 'method'=>'POST', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'])!!}
        <div class="form-group"> 
            {{Form::textarea('value', null, ['id'=>'value', 'placeholder'=>'Insert here', 'name'=>'value'])}}
        </div>

        {{Form::submit('submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary', 'type'=>'submit', 'id'=>'submit'])}}

    {!!Form::close()!!}
</html>
```

I get the error below when submitting:

> **SQLSTATE[23000]:** Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'restaurant_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into reviews (user_id, restaurant_id, value, updated_at, created_at) values (1, ?, kkkkbkb, 2019-07-11 08:39:10, 2019-07-11 08:39:10))

Comment: what is your `$request->route('id')` value?

Comment: Where/how are you passing the `id` for the restaraunt? You're attempting to grab it from the route in the `Request` object but dont appear to be setting it.

Comment: check your restaurant_id column and define it null. maybe the id is not getting any variable value and you are trying to store it. probably, the restaurant_id is define not null

Comment: You probably should set form action like this `Form::open(['action' => ['ReviewsController@store', $restaurant_id], ...`

Comment: @IncOre am getting the error Undefined variable: restaurant_id (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\restaurantFinder\resources\views\restaurants\review.blade.php)

Comment: @Unflux where am i supposed to set it?  i passed it on the review route Route::get('/restaurants/{id}/review', ['as' => 'restaurants.review', 'uses' => 'ReviewsController@show']);

Comment: @MatildahMariwa - You need to set it on your form action if you have set it as a parameter in your route.

Answer (score 0):

where do you get this value? `$request->route('id');`. the restaurant_id is not seeing this `$request->route('id');`

Comment: from the review blade URL which contains restaurant's id

Answer (score 0):

I was using XAMPP myself. I had to stop then restart apache and MySQL which resolved the problem.